# convert html_nodes to data frame in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am extracting data from a web page

```
url <- "https://www.lacolonia.com/vinagre-tinto-carbonell-250-ml-ref8410010855064/p"
```

I want all the data in a data_frame

```
html <- read_html(url) #leyendo HTML
productos <- html_nodes(html,".product-details , .skuBestPrice") #extrayendo el HTML en bruto
links5 <- html_nodes(productos, "a")
links6 <- bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(links5), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
```

The links do not have some data from "productos", missing the price value

productos brind me this information

```
[1] <div class="row product-details "><div class="">\n<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm description-prod"><div class="c ...
[2] <strong productindex="0" class="skuBestPrice">L. 75.90</strong>
```

I need in the data_frame the value= 75.90, can you help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.lacolonia.com/vinagre-tinto-carbonell-250-ml-ref8410010855064/p"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('p.descricao-preco strong.skuBestPrice') %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  sub('.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1', .) %>% as.numeric()
  #For optional decimal numbers 
  #sub('.*?(\\d+\\.?\\d?).*', '\\1', .) %>% as.numeric()

#[1] 75.9
```

Comment: Thank you, is very helpfull, If I want put the product description, what code i have to add

Comment: I get the output but i don´t know how to save "url" as data frame

Comment: @RobertoRamirez After `as.numeric` in the end add `as.numeric() %>% as.data.frame -> data` ?